# How to display the description of the item without the ID

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My code is this:

```
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$db) or die("Connect Failed: %s\\n". $conn-\>error);

    $category=$_POST['category'];
    
    if($category==1)
    {
        $RetStockPHP="SELECT id, CONCAT(imei,', ',brand,', ',model) AS Eqname FROM tbl_equipment";
        if($res1=mysqli_query($conn,$RetStockPHP))
        {
            if(mysqli_num_rows($res1)>0)
            {
                while($row1=$res1->fetch_assoc())
                {
                                
                    $idPHP1=$row1['id'];
                    $EqnamePHP1=$row1['Eqname'];
                    echo "<option value='$idPHP1'>$EqnamePHP1</option>";
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $RetStockPHP="select it.id as itemcode, concat(art.description,', ',it.description,', ',ut.description) as fitem , category from ref_item as it left join ref_article as art on it.article_id = art.id left join ref_unit as ut on it.unit = ut.id order by it.id;";
        if($res1=mysqli_query($conn,$RetStockPHP))
        {
            if(mysqli_num_rows($res1)>0)
            {
                while($row1=$res1->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $ItemcodePHP1=$row1['itemcode'];
                    $fitemPHP1=$row1['fitem'];
                    echo "<option value='$ItemcodePHP1'>$fitemPHP1</option>";
            
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The result is like this for Supplies:

`2|Ballpen, blue, 2mm tip, box`

and for equipment:

`20220010201|IMEI-12345, ASUS, VIVOBOOK 14.`

How do I not display the ID?

Sorry Newbie here. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you output a `<select>` somewhere? Since you're using `<option>`s. If you don't, don't use `<option>` but only `echo $EqnamePHP1;` and `echo $fitemPHP1;`

Comment: From what you've shown it's unclear how this would be occurring. Please make sure what you've shown us is a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: I have a <select class="form-control" list="listitem" id="CategoryHTML" placeholder=""> for category which has an <option value="">Supplies</option> and <option value="1">Equipment</option>. What I'm trying to do is if you select an option the code will display the Item description in a dropbox which is <label for="inputEmail4">Item Description</label>          <input class="form-control" list="listitem" id="ItemidHTML" placeholder="">

Comment: The result of the code is if you select the supplies option, it will display in the dropbox the id and description which is 2|Ballpen, blue, 2mm tip, box. But if select that supply it will only display the number 2 which is the id.

Comment: Thank you for your help @brombeer and ADyson...i found the problem...<input class="form-control" list="listitem" id="ItemidHTML" placeholder="">..changed that to <select id="itdesc"class="form-control" >